# android view pager edit code

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager

how are you ? 
i just found a code that let me create tabs and navigate through tabs in my android application... but in fact i faced a little problem 
in this code the name of the tabs is Section + its number position 
i am wondering if i can change the name of every tab and every name can be different

here's the code coders :

```
package com.example.android.effectivenavigation;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
    // parent.
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
 * sections of the app.
 */
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
                return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

            default:
                // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Section " + (position + 1);
    }
}

/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

        // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_collection_button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CollectionDemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // Demonstration of navigating to external activities.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_external_activity)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Create an intent that asks the user to pick a photo, but using
                        // FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET, ensures that relaunching
                        // the application from the device home screen does not return
                        // to the external activity.
                        Intent externalActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        externalActivityIntent.setType("image/*");
                        externalActivityIntent.addFlags(
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                        startActivity(externalActivityIntent);
                    }
                });

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tab title is appearing as `Section + its number` because you are setting it that way when creating the tabs in your code - `.setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))`. See below...

```
    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)) //this is where the title is set
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
```

Set the text `.setText()` as your desire.

For example, a simple way is to check the counter and set the title appropriately...

```
for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    // one simple way 
    if(i == 0) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("First Tab")
            .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

See [**ActionBar DOCS**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)